# Best path to learn C64 assembly

Tags: commodore-64, programming, assembly, reference-request

The amount of tutorials, youtube videos, scanned books on C64 programming is overwhelming.

What materials would you recommend -- and, importantly, in what order! -- to build a path to programming my own demo in Assembly?

Please assume programming knowledge in higher-level languages.

Comment: @Wilson: I started reading scanned "Commodore Programmer Reference Guide", and some resources at 6502.org, but the more I look around, the more material I see. That's why I need recommendations from those who have already been there and know which books/links/etc. are more useful than other.

Comment: If truly a beginner: https://skilldrick.github.io/easy6502/

Comment: I would highly recommend the book "Machine Language for Beginners" to learn the basics of 6502 ML and a copy of "Mapping the Commodore 64" - those two books will make you invincible.

Comment: A knowledge of 6502 is required. This file http://www.zimmers.net/cbmpics/cbm/c64/vic-ii.txt describes almost everything important to code the 64 beast -- but not SID and not CIA ports. SID is virtually unimportant if you use tools like music editors that give you complete playable 'modules'. CIAs are pretty simple things and info about them acting in C64 is spread elsewhere (googlable).

Answer (score 5):

Since you want to program demo's you will have to learn not only 6510 machine code, but also the hardware of the c64. Both are explained in the original ['Commodore 64 Programmer's Reference Guide'](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/Commodore_64_Programmer's_Reference_Guide). In my opinion this book is sufficient to do whatever you want to do with the c64.

The only other book I bought was the [What's Really Inside the Commodore 64 by Milton Bathurst](https://books.google.be/books/about/What_s_Really_Inside_the_Commodore_64.html?id=ETfdtgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y). This is a disassembly of the c64 roms.

Comment: If by *demo* you mean the graphically intensive psychedelic animations with music you can see on YouTube - there's a lot of advanced tricks you can do with the VIC and SID that you will NOT glean from that text, such as the disappearing border trick, playing samples through the SID, FLI/IFLI modes, etc.

Comment: @LawrenceC. Thanks. I will start from that text, but after that what sources would you recommend?

Comment: Go through the old Compute!'s Gazette and/or RUN magazines if you can find them on an online archive site somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You've probably already seen [6502.org](http://6502.org). It has a lot of tutorials. Also, if you haven't yet downloaded [CBM.prg Studio](http://www.ajordison.co.uk) you should have a look at it.